# Installing Sphinx on Railsinstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, railsinstaller

I used railsinstaller to install rails into OS Windows.
To work with project I use Aptana. And I want to use gem "thinking-sphinx", "~> 2.0.13" into my project.

When I started indexes -
**rake thinking_sphinx:index**
- I have a mistake

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name
```

Sphinx.yml

```
development:
  port: 9312
  config_file: "RAILS_ROOT/config/development.sphinx.conf"
  searchd_log_file: "RAILS_ROOT/log/searchd.log"
  query_log_file: "RAILS_ROOT/log/searchd.query.log"
  pid_file: "RAILS_ROOT/log/searchd.development.pid"
  bin_path: '/usr/local/bin'
  searchd_binary_name: 'searchd'
  indexer_binary_name: 'indexer'
test:
  port: 9313
production:
  port: 9312
```

How to use sphinx via gem in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx isn't a gem, but a separate program that thinking sphinx is a interface to.

Windows installation ripon instructions are on the sphinx website here - http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/installing-windows.html